# MySQL search in two tables and return results from the first table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables **Products** and **Items**.

each **product** contains **items** relationship by `product_id`

**Products** table :

```
| id    | name          |
|----   |-----------    |
| 1     | Product 1     |
| 2     | Product 2     |
```

**Items** table :

```
| id    | product_id    | name      |
|----   |------------   |--------   |
| 1     | 1             | Item 1    |
| 2     | 2             | Item 2    |
```

So i have searching ability for table **Products** :

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%product 1%'
```

What i'm trying to achieve is the ability to search also on **Items** table if the there's an item matching return it's parent **Product**.

So if i search for **Item 1** and it's linked to **Product 1** by `product_id` then return **Product 1**

I've tried :

```
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%product 1%') UNION (SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%item 1%')
```

When the search keywords matches `Product 1` it returns the product, but if search keywords is `Item 1` it returns the `item` not the `product`, and i want in all cases to return only `products`.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: JOIN the tables to get related items

Comment: JOINs are one of the basic relational database operations, any tutorial should cover it.

Answer (score 2):

You can `LEFT JOIN` the two tables to each other on `product_id` and then search in both `name` fields to find a match, returning the product name if you do. We use a `LEFT JOIN` so that products that don't have items can still be searched. For example (searching for a product name):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN items i ON i.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.name LIKE '%Product 1%'
   OR i.name LIKE '%Product 1%'
```

Output:

```
id  name
1   Product 1
```

Or searching for an item name:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN items i ON i.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.name LIKE '%Item 1%'
   OR i.name LIKE '%Item 1%'
```

Output:

```
id  name
1   Product 1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ayZBwLGHsMsXRKbL289Y99/2)

Comment: Thanks Nick! but here's a notice, this query is taking a bit load and time comparing to @Barmar's answer which is fast. what causes this? for future upcommers. appreciate your help!

Comment: @AmrSubZero MySQL is (unfortunately) notoriously bad at optimising queries with `OR` in a `WHERE` clause. Other DBMS don't tend to have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to UNION with a JOIN.

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE name LIKE '%search term%'

UNION

SELECT p.*
FROM products AS p
JOIN items AS i ON p.id = i.product_id
WHERE i.name LIKE '%search term%'
```

Comment: How is this different from just using an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause of the second part of the query?

Comment: The JOIN will only return products that have items.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
select p.*
from products p
where p.name LIKE '%search term%' or
      exists (select 1
              from items i
              where i.product_id = p.id and
                    i.name LIKE '%search term%'
             );
```

With this formulation, you don't have to worry about duplicates if multiple items match a product.